# Running docker image with a separate local gemspec

Tags: ruby, docker, rubygems, docker-compose, dockerfile

Currently we have a Dockerfile to create our test image.

```
FROM ruby:2.4

USER root

ENV LOCAL_GEM_PATH ./../qa-common/

RUN /bin/bash -l -c "gem install nokogiri -v 1.8 --no-ri --no-rdoc"


COPY Gemfile* /tmp/
COPY qa-common $LOCAL_GEM_PATH
WORKDIR /tmp

#================================================================
# Installs gems . Put frequently changed commands (COPY, ADD)
# after this as section as much possible to insure a quick build
#================================================================

RUN /bin/bash -l -c "gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc"
RUN /bin/bash -l -c "bundle install"

COPY . /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

CMD ["-T"]

ENTRYPOINT ["bundle", "exec", "ruby", "bin/run_tests_from_queue.rb"]
```

We are running into an error where the bundle install in the Dockerfile cannot find the qa-common gem (which is a local repository on my machine with a .gempspec)

Normally without docker, the current project's gemfile specifies so changes we make to qa-common can be tested on our local machine

```
gem 'qa-common', :path => local_gem_directory
```

Everything we've tried is preventing this bundle install because it either cannot find the gem/gemspec or because qa-common is outside the test directory (where the Dockerfile resides).

What is the best practice or solution to this problem so that when we create an image to run tests that depends on this qa-common gem, we can use the local qa-common version on our machine to test our changes to qa-common has not broken anything?

Answer (score 1):

I've been dealing with a very similar issue, and think this is working for me:

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

gem_path = ENV.fetch('LOCAL_GEM_PATH', '.')

gem 'my_personal_gem', path: File.join(gem_path, 'my_personal_gem')
```

Then you can set `LOCAL_GEM_PATH` to where the directory containing the Gems are.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This has helped me after a day of head scratching and trying loads of different things. Thanks. I've set LOCAL_GEM_PATH as an environment variable in the docker-compose.yml file so it's only set when building. If you want to edit your local gem in development you'll need to make sure you mount your gem as a volume inside the container.